# Xaml - Bitmap UriSource - absolute path works, relative path does not, why?

Tags: wpf, xaml, relative-path

I'm, a WPF & Xaml-noob, for console applications it has worked for me to simply give the relative path to the executable to access a file.
It doesn't seem to work in xaml for me. (code at the bottom)
Absolute path works perfectly.

**Is it possible in XAML in a WPF-application to access a file by simply using a relative path to the directory of your executable as a valid UriSource? If yes how and if not why not?**

I found the following question, where they were talking about adding the file via Visual Studio's "Add existing item", so it seems like a different issue.

[How can I set the WPF BitmapImage UriSource property to a relative path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180427/how-can-i-set-the-wpf-bitmapimage-urisource-property-to-a-relative-path)

```
<Window.Icon>
  <!--absolute path works:-->
  <BitmapImage UriSource="C:\LongPath\SolutionFolder\ProjectFolder\bin\Debug\path4.ico" />

  <!--none of the following relative paths worked:-->
  <!--AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory returns the Debug-folder-->
  <!--<BitmapImage UriSource="path4.ico" />-->
  <!--<BitmapImage UriSource="../path4.ico" />-->
  <!--<BitmapImage UriSource="Debug/path4.ico" />-->
  <!--<BitmapImage UriSource="bin/Debug/path4.ico" />-->
  <!--<BitmapImage UriSource="../bin/Debug/path4.ico" />-->
  <!--<BitmapImage UriSource="../../bin/Debug/path4.ico" />-->
  <!--<BitmapImage UriSource="../Debug/path4.ico" />-->
</Window.Icon>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

URIs can be confusing, as they can refer to both files on disk and resources in the application. So a relative path could be to a resource in the app, when you intend it to be on disk.

You can use the [siteoforigin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#The_siteoforigin_____Authority) authority to force relative file URIs. [This blog](http://nerddawg.blogspot.com/2005/12/more-on-resource-loading-in-wpf.html) explains this more, but here an example:

```
pack://siteoforigin:,,,/path4.ico
```

Comment: Is the pack:// URI scheme relevant outside of a Metro execution context?  Would that scheme be relevant to a WPF app running under Windows 7?  All of these documentation links suggest that the scheme is only relevant to Metro, but we're struggling with this problem under Windows 7.

Comment: @ardave - This answer was specific to WPF and posted well before Metro or WinRT was a thing.

Answer (score 4):

Relative paths without qualifications look up the referenced file in the application resources, if a path should be relative to the executable you can use `pack://siteoforigin:,,,/path4.ico`, see [Pack URIs on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx).

Comment: How does this work for relative paths "Above" the calling file? For example if there are 2 files with the name path4.ico. Is there a hierarchical search that will return the closest file in sense of "depth distance"?

Comment: @Mechandrius 
I am pretty sure you have to point directly to the file, so if you want to go up one level the path ends with `../path4.ico` and for up two levels you get `../../path4.ico`. Have never tried that though.