# Binding Relative Path for BitmapImage UriSource

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following:

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding resource}" />
```

Where resource is a string in a class that holds a location to an image. This works when resource is an absolute path, but doesn't when the path is relative.

I understand I have to use [pack URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6111470/xaml-bitmap-urisource-absolute-path-works-relative-path-does-not-why). But how do I implement it in this case?

Comment: can you show actual paths when it works and when it dont??

Answer (score 2):

Below are 3 ways you can have images in your project.

a. Add image directly into the project, right-click on image, select properties and set Build Action -> Resource. This will compile image into assembly (exe/dll)

```
<Image Source="Grapes.png" Stretch="None"></Image>
```

If you created some folder say "Images" inside your project and add images into that folder then path would be

```
<Image Source="Images\Grapes.png" Stretch="None"></Image>
```

b. Add image directly into the project, right-click on image, select properties and set Build Action -> Content and "Copy to output directory" to "Copy Always". This will copy the images file beside to EXE in the folder where EXE is created. (bin\debug or bin\release)

```
<Image Source="Orange.png" Stretch="None"></Image>
```

If you created some folder say "Images" inside your project and add images into that folder then path would be

```
<Image Source="Images\Orange.png" Stretch="None"></Image>
```

c. Do not add image into the folder. Instead copy image directly into folder where EXE will be created (bin\debug or bin\release). When you run the application, siteoforigin will be equal to location of your executable.

```
<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Apple.png" Stretch="None"></Image>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using pack URI for the string which hold a location to an Image

```
pack://siteoforigin:,,,/yourimagefilename.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks! This should work but I have a problem. My relative path actually goes up 1 level like: "../Data/myImage.jpg". After I did what you suggest, I get a `DirectoryNotFoundException` stating could not find a part of the path. In the path, I noticed that the ".." had disappeared so it became "Bin/Data/myImage.jpg" instead.

Comment: I think when you deploy your application, your Data folder would be located beside your executable. So in this case you would not required to go one level up. During development time, you can copy your data folder in bin\debug or bin\release folder.

Comment: Actually I can't, the folder is 1 level above the executable during deployment time... and I'm required to use the folder...